# I can't solve "Method Not Allowed Exceptions" in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

The method not allowed exceptions is shown as follow, The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

````
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header card-header-success">
                    <h4>Account Registration Form</h4>
                </div>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('accounts.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="commentForm">
                        @csrf
                        <!-- Codes -->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::resource("accounts", "AccountController");
Route::get('/accounts', 'AccountController@create');
Route::post('/accounts', 'AccountController@create');
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Define routes only once in routes/web.php.

Remove the following lines:

```
Route::get('/accounts', 'AccountController@create');
Route::post('/accounts', 'AccountController@create');
```

The resource route definition provides in the `accounts.store` route if you matched the controller methods to the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers).

Make sure that your `AccountController` also contains a function called `store`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this route

```
Route::get('/accounts', 'AccountController@create')->name('accounts.create');
```

```
Route::post('/accounts', 'AccountController@store')->name('accounts.store');
```

not post

Comment: To know you can remain only
Route::resource("accounts", "AccountController");
-You can check this in the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers
If this answer helpful and useful ,plz accept it to help others

Answer (score 0):

This because you overwrote your routes if you need to run routes below resources you need to give them same name of route like this
`Route::post('/accounts', 'AccountController@create')->name('accounts.store');`
Or if you want to use resources routes you need to put it below of your routes to avoid overwrite its name and urls